# How to setup test cases for SAPUI5/OPENUI5 applications?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, sapui5

I try to atomize my tests for a given UI5 application. Therefore I created a folder under WebContent called test-resources. In that folder I placed two files for first tests.

First file: experimental.qunit.html that contains some first working unit test code.

Second file: experimental.opa.html which contains an example code from the documentation.

The testing part looks like this:

```
opaTest("Should find a Button with a matching property", function(Given, When, Then) {
    // Act
    Given.iStartMyAppInAFrame("index.html");

    When.waitFor({
        viewName : "view.master.Master",
        controlType : "sap.m.Button",
        matchers : new sap.ui.test.matchers.PropertyStrictEquals({
            name : "icon",
            value : "sap-icon://show"
        }),
        success : function (aButtons) {
            debugger;
            ok(true, "Found the button: " + aButtons[0]);
        },
        errorMessage : "No button with property icon equal to sap-icon://show"
    });
    Then.waitFor({
        // not implemented
    });
    Then.iTeardownMyAppFrame();
});
```

First of all I assume that I can search a button also with icon property.
Second assumption is, that `viewName` is the name and folder of the view file? In the app, the view is the master view of a split app.

I start the test like this:
* In Eclipse mark the project and choose run as "Web App Preview"
* Than of course I see my normal app
* I replace the index.html part with test-resoruces/experimental.opa.html
* Now I can see the test and my app is shown in an iframe

But:
1. The button selection is not working, anyone an idea what's wrong?
2. If I change the html code I have to restart the "Web App Preview" all the time, a reload seems not working. Is there a "better" way to run the tests after updating test code?

The app itself is defined as a component, and the main view is a SplitApp xml file that contains nothing than:

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <SplitApp id="idAppControl" />
</mvc:View>
```

Meanwhile I detect the problem and fixed it. My syntax of `PropertyStrictEquals` was wrong.

The restart problem (of Web App Preview) still exists.

I also detected a helpful example:
https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/test/BuyProductJourney.qunit.html

It is mentioned here:
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/10/16/javascript-based-integration-tests-for-sapui5-apps-with-opa

Answer (score 1):

*(Have a look at the testing Tutorial in the [developper guide](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/291c9121e6044ab381e0b51716f97f52.html))*

First of all, in your example you are mixing the levels of abstraction. Directly in your **jurney** (the order of steps for your tests) there should not be any code like `waitFor()`, because that is page specific code. So you should create **pages**, on where your actual arrangements, actions and assertions take place. In the jurney you only call them. like this *([source](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/291c9121e6044ab381e0b51716f97f52.html))*:

```
        opaTest("Should see the post page when a user clicks on an entry of the list", function (Given, When, Then) {
        // Arrangements
        Given.iStartMyApp();

        //Actions
        When.onTheWorklistPage.iPressOnTheItemWithTheID("PostID_15");

        // Assertions
        Then.onThePostPage.theTitleShouldDisplayTheName("Jeans");
    });
```

Those objects `onTheWorklistPage` and `onThePostPage` are your actual test steps, wher you search for objects and trigger a click or check the displayed text you create them like that:

```
    Opa5.createPageObjects({
        onTheWorklistPage: {
            baseClass: Common,
            actions: {...},
            assertions: {...}
        }
    })
```

Now in those actions and assertions you put your  `waitFor()` to get elements and do something with them. This function is described in the [API](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.test.Opa5.html#waitFor)

PS: Your question is very unstructured and I am not shure if I answered your question, if not, please comment.